# Is the tab being shared/recorded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using the `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` it shows a media selector window. Can I get the info whether the user selected a tab or window?

If its not possible then, can using some js code I can find out whether a tab is being shared/recorded or not? When a tab is shared it shows an indicator in the tab header, but hot to get that info programmatically?

Comment: check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/getAll

Comment: Nope, it did't help